# What happened to Zuko's mother?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In *The Legend of Korra*, Jinora asks Katara what happened to Zuko's mother, and in *The Last Airbender*, it is only revealed that she was banished for killing Fire Lord Azulon.

Comment: There is comic book series that explains what happened. It's called [*The Search*](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Search).

Comment: I heard about this on avatar.wikia.com but couldn't find any real information. Also I don't know where to buy the comic series.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is revealed in *The Search*, a comic book set after the events of *The last airbender*:

> Zuko's mother used to live in a simple village along with her boyfriend. Then the Fire Lord Azulon, upon finding the location, decided to marry her to his son, prince Ozai. This is because he found out that she was avatar Roku's daughter, and wanted to strengthen the royal bloodline.
> It seemed like Roku tried to hide her for that very reason. She couldn't refuse. Fast forward several years, she kept sending secret letters to her boyfriend in the village. She suspected that the letters were being intercepted, so she wrote a lie in one of these letters implying that Zuko is actually the son of her and the boyfriend, rather than Ozai's.
>  As suspected, Ozai was indeed intercepting the letters; he was furious with that lie (he knew that it was a lie because he had spied on her for several months before meeting her) and confronted her. He decided that as punishment, he would indeed treat Zuko as if he wasn't his own son. Years later, when Azulon commands Ozai to kill his firstborn to have a taste of Iroh's loss during the war, Ozai accepted immediately.
>  Zuko's mother stopped him and offered him a deal: she would make a poison that Ozai could use to kill Azulon and take the throne, in exchange for sparing Zuko. He accepted, but at the condition that she would leave the palace because he feared her ability to make such deadly poison. Zuko's mother went back to the village where she found her boyfriend again. They met a spirit with the ability to change someone's face and memories, and she decided to get a new face and erase her memories (so she forgot about Zuko, Ozai, Azula, Roku, etc) and lived happily. After the events of *The Last Airbender*, Zuko asks for Aang's help to find her. Azula also helps. They find her and restore her memories. She stays at the village.

Comment: *Such* a letdown.

Comment: I thought that Ursa was Roku's granddaughter, because Roku is Zuko's great-grandfather. And how can Roku have hidden her, when he died before he was born and couldn't act through Aang?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs: Roku hid Ursa when she was young — before his death, her marriage to Ozai, and the events of the original series.  Her whereabouts during the events of the series is explained further in the spoiler-tagged section of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Zuko's Mother Ursa left because she was banished for trying to save Zuko from death. She then went to the mother of faces for her to get a new face and for her memories of Firelord Ozai and the children to be erased. It is later revealed that the kids met their mother in the village. She changed her name. After that, Zuko asked if his mother could get her face and memories back. He then let his mother come back to live with him.

Answer (score 0):

At Firelord Azulon's burial they said "Firelord Ozai was husband to Alia (Zuko's mother), who is now passed" - meaning she died, making the following comic invalid!

Comment: or the official story is that she was dead, when she had actually been exiled.

Comment: Every good covert assassination needs a cover story.

Comment: Having re-watched the coronation, Ilah (proper spelling) is Azulon's wife, not Ozai's. They are listing all of Azulon's direct relations. That doesn't include Azulon's daughter-in-law, or any other in-laws.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-watched that episode and they meant that Firelord Azulon was the husband of Iylah and not Firelord Ozai. So the story still stands.

Comment: Ilah isn't Zuko's mother, she's presumably Zuko's grandmother. So, while I believe you, your answer has nothing to do with the question here.

Comment: if anything, this should be a comment on gideon_rocks's answer

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the *Avatar Airbender* series, when Zuko's dad was in jail, Zuko went to go meet him in the last episode and he asked "*where is my mother?*" which implies that she is alive but her whereabouts are unknown.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, plus the accepted answer does explain what happened. So unless you have some further information to add, this seems like it could have been posted as a comment.

Comment: *he asked "where is my mother?" which implies that she is alive but her whereabouts are unknown.* No, it really doesn't. At most, it implies that Zuko *thinks* she's alive.